# Indexing in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Given a lookup table:

```
colors = [  [0,0,0],\
            [0, 255, 0],\
            [0, 0, 255],\
            [255, 0, 0]]
```

And an index numpy matrix input 2x2:

```
a = np.array([[0,1],[1,1]])
```

How can I map a to a 2x2x3 matrix b, where `b[i][j] = colors[a[i][j]]`? I want to avoid using a for loop here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
colors[a]
```

Here's a full example:

```
import numpy as np

colors = np.array([[0,0,0],
                   [0, 255, 0],
                   [0, 0, 255],
                   [255, 0, 0]
                  ])
a = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 1]])

new = colors[a]
new.shape
# (2, 2, 3)
new
# array([[[  0,   0,   0],
#         [  0, 255,   0]],
#
#        [[  0, 255,   0],
#         [  0, 255,   0]]])
```

Comment: Note that you redefine colors here using numpy array otherwise you get an error with "OP colors".

Comment: @agstudy, very true. If `colors` is a list of lists you can only index it using slices or integers.